# Unable to open socket to url with path

Tags: c#

I am trying to create socket in order to connect with server. Problem is that server keeps socket on specific path like `localhost:8050/adapter/interface`
I tried different things like below but without any result. Each time i receive that host is not known

```
string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
string myip = Dns.GetHostByName(hostname).AddressList[0].ToString();
dsSocket = new TcpClient(myip+ "/adapter/interface/", 8050);
```

I have JS code like below:
 `dsm_webSocket = new WebSocket(dsm_webSocketUrl);`
where url is like below:
`"ws://localhost:8050/adapter/interface"`

I am trying to do the same connection but in C#

Comment: A socket doesn't open URLs (or "paths"), only a host and a port. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: You can't use TcpClient to access a web page directly.

Comment: @szpic a websocket is something completely different than a socket. A socket is, as others already said, just a tcp connection where "you can send and receive bytes". A websocket however is upgrade of a HTTP request where client and server agree to open a permanent socket. So in order to open a websocket, your client must send http requests to the server. For C#, you will probably just have to use `WebSocketClient` class instead of `TcpClient` for what you're trying to do. It will send the http requests automatically and open a websocket connection for you.